# CREATE TABLE ... LIKE error message in Oracle: 00922. 00000 - "missing or invalid option"

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a new table with the same attributes as an old one, but without the data.

However, when I try this:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE old_table;
```

I get the following error message:

> 922. 00000 -  "missing or invalid option"

What am I missing?
I'm also open to alternative solutions, I just don't understand why this is not working.

Comment: Other databases might allow that syntax - [like MySQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-8.0-en/create-table-like.html) - but Oracle RDBMS does not. The allowed syntax is [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html) (but for your version). You might want `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT ...`, but that doesn't recreate constraints, indexes etc.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE new_table AS (SELECT * FROM old_table WHERE 1=2);
```

or this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE new_tbl SELECT * FROM orig_tbl LIMIT 0;
```

maybe the root of your problem can be found here
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-8.0-en/create-table-like.html

Comment: MySQL RDMBS is not the same as Oracle RDBMS and the question is asking about Oracle. Oracle does not support the `LIMIT` keyword and your linked documentation is for MySQL and not Oracle.